# Can you adjust Aperture in [Tv] mode on a PowerShot G7 X?

Tags: canon, aperture, powershot, shooting-mode, shutter-priority

I do not own a PowerShot G7 X, but my friend does.

We want to know if it is possible to adjust the aperture when in [Tv] mode, so that she can try for milky water on a waterfall.

Is this possible?

Comment: On the assumption that the G7 X has manual mode, why not just use that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The whole point of Tv mode is that you *don't* adjust the aperture; the camera meters the scene and calculates the aperture based on the selected shutter speed and ISO setting. If you want to adjust the aperture, use Av or M mode.

As to the "milky water", I think what you're actually looking for is a slow shutter speed to blur the water. Your aperture setting isn't as important here. In Tv mode, set a slow shutter speed and use a tripod to avoid camera shake. Since a long shutter speed is required  to capture this effect, conditions can simply be too bright for the shutter speed needed, so use a low ISO setting, and possibly also a ND filter.

Comment: The G7X, like most Canon enthusiast compacts, has a built in 3 stop ND filter, which basically means you should get 8 times the shutter time for the same exposure without it turned on.